# Interlis Encoding Problem

Tags: qgis, encoding, interlis

Right now, I start using Interlis in QGIS (I never used Interlis before...). However, there seems to be a systematical encoding problem. When I select the transfer file and start the import, the following error message appears:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4'
 in position 40: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What do I need to change (step by step)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @NiklausZihlmann! Haven't used Interlis before either but what seems to be a common reason for your `UnicodeEncodeError` error is the username containing symbols or accents. Does your username contains these ASCII characters?

Comment: @Joseph: no, it does not... the username is just 'nz'...

Comment: What is the default encoding of QGIS? is it ASCII? If yes, is there a way to change it to UTF-8? Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

An Interlis 1 transfer file (`.itf`) is always ISO-8859-1 encoded. An Interlis 2 transfer file (`.xtf`) is an XML file; the rules of XML apply (the encoding declaration in the xml prolog defines the encoding; default is UTF-8).